# Not sure why my Python code that uses Spacy to add a phone_number entity is not working

Tags: nlp, spacy, spacy-3

The pattern works with matcher.  But not as an entity? Here is my code:

```
import spacy
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRuler

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

patterns = [
    {
        "label": "PHONE_NUMBER",
        "pattern": [
            {"ORTH": "("},
            {"SHAPE": "ddd"},
            {"ORTH": ")"},
            {"IS_SPACE": True, "OP": "?"},
            {"SHAPE": "ddd"},
            {"ORTH": "-"},
            {"SHAPE": "dddd"},
        ],
    }
]

entity_ruler = EntityRuler(nlp, patterns=patterns, overwrite_ents=True)
nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", before="ner")

doc = nlp("You can reach me at (111) 111-1111.")

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

This returns:

```
111 CARDINAL
111 CARDINAL
```

Advice/help needed and appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was two seperate components—one constructed with the class `EntityRuler` and one constructed with `nlp.add_pipe`. The component created with the `add_pipe` method wasn't aware of your patterns. Using just one method and then adding the patterns to that component did the trick.

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
patterns = [
    {
        "label": "PHONE_NUMBER",
        "pattern": [
            {"ORTH": "("},
            {"SHAPE": "ddd"},
            {"ORTH": ")"},
            {"IS_SPACE": True, "OP": "?"},
            {"SHAPE": "ddd"},
            {"ORTH": "-"},
            {"SHAPE": "dddd"},
        ],
    }
]

ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", before="ner")
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)

doc = nlp("You can reach me at (111) 111-1111.")

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

```
(111) 111-1111 PHONE_NUMBER
```

I read about the different ways to initialize the component here: https://spacy.io/api/entityruler

Comment: Thank you.  I really appreciate your kind response.  It works.  Going back to the docs to see why I missed that (because of course now it seems obvious...).